# Custom FPS Controller in Unity 5.6.6f2 not letting me look up or down

Tags: unity, c#

Due to the FPS Controller seeming to be broken in Unity now, I started using a custom one by kinifi on GitHub. For some reason though I can't look up or down. I removed the Main Camera so it should of fixed it but no. Is there anything I can change in this script to allow me to look up and down.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class FPS : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float speed = 5.0f;
    private float m_MovX;
    private float m_MovY;
    private Vector3 m_moveHorizontal;
    private Vector3 m_movVertical;
    private Vector3 m_velocity;
    private Rigidbody m_Rigid;
    private float m_yRot;
    private float m_xRot;
    private Vector3 m_rotation;
    private Vector3 m_cameraRotation;
    private float m_lookSensitivity = 3.0f;
    private bool m_cursorIsLocked = true;

    [Header("The Camera the player looks through")]
    public Camera m_Camera;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        m_Rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {

        m_MovX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        m_MovY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        m_moveHorizontal = transform.right * m_MovX;
        m_movVertical = transform.forward * m_MovY;

        m_velocity = (m_moveHorizontal + m_movVertical).normalized * speed;

        //mouse movement 
        m_yRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        m_rotation = new Vector3(0, m_yRot, 0) * m_lookSensitivity;

        m_xRot = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
        m_cameraRotation = new Vector3(m_xRot, 0, 0) * m_lookSensitivity;

        //apply camera rotation

        //move the actual player here
        if (m_velocity != Vector3.zero)
        {
            m_Rigid.MovePosition(m_Rigid.position + m_velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        if (m_rotation != Vector3.zero)
        {
            //rotate the camera of the player
            m_Rigid.MoveRotation(m_Rigid.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(m_rotation));
        }

        if (m_Camera != null)
        {
            //negate this value so it rotates like a FPS not like a plane
            m_Camera.transform.Rotate(-m_cameraRotation);
        }

        InternalLockUpdate();

    }

    //controls the locking and unlocking of the mouse
    private void InternalLockUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = false;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            m_cursorIsLocked = true;
        }

        if (m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            UnlockCursor();
        }
        else if (!m_cursorIsLocked)
        {
            LockCursor();
        }
    }

    private void UnlockCursor()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    private void LockCursor()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: So, first things to check: is `m_Camera` null, or is `m_lookSensitivity` zero?

Comment: m_camera is at null, m_lookSensitivity is at 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a camera object to the `m_Camera` variable so that the script knows which camera you want to rotate.

When `m_Camera` is null, this script silently skips over the vertical camera movement code to avoid triggering a null reference exception.

Since this variable is public, it should show up as a "Camera" slot you can edit in the Unity Inspector for this script. Drag a camera object into that slot, or click the circle next to it to choose an available camera from a list.

Comment: I can look up and down but now not left or right

Comment: Were you able to look left & right before? Is your camera a child of the Rigidbody object?

Comment: Yes and Yes, and now I'm rotating even with rotation locked. I also need to know how to jump since that's not included as well.

Comment: Have you got an idea DM

Answer (score -2):

I no longer use the kinifi controller, I just tried using Standard Assets again and it worked!